# Table (Login) has no column named (A_NAME )(code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Login(A_NAME,A_PHONE) VALUES (?,?)

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

```
public class DBhandle {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "restaurantdatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    final Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    //table name
    private static final String LOGIN_TABLE_NAME = "Login";

    //login table column name
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "ID";
    public static final String A_NAME = "admin_name";
    public static final String A_PHONE = "admin_phone";

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + LOGIN_TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + A_NAME
                            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + A_PHONE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
            );
        }

        public long insertEntry(String userName, String password) {
            //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
            // Assign values for each row.
            newValues.put("A_NAME", userName);
            newValues.put("A_PHONE", password);

            // Insert the row into your table
            return ourDatabase.insert(LOGIN_TABLE_NAME, null, newValues);
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to insert data into a database I receive the following exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Login has no column named A_NAME (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Login(A_NAME,A_PHONE) VALUES (?,?).
```

Comment: Simply remove (") double cot around key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the columns "A_NAME" and "A_PHONE" as strings, when these are actually final static String constants, so the actual column names are "admin_name" and "admin_phone".

You need to change these two lines:

```
// Assign values for each row.
newValues.put("A_NAME", userName);
newValues.put("A_PHONE", password);
```

You have two options:

You either refer to the actual column names:

```
newValues.put("admin_name", userName);
newValues.put("admin_phone", password);
```

or use the static final constants without double quotes

```
newValues.put(A_NAME, userName);
newValues.put(A_PHONE, password);
```

Comment: whoever is down voting the answer please specify a reason in the comments

Answer (score 0):

```
public long insertEntry(String userName,String password)
{
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put(A_NAME, userName);
    newValues.put(A_PHONE, password);


    // Insert the row into your table
    return ourDatabase.insert(LOGIN_TABLE_NAME, null, newValues);
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Change your insertEntry() Method With This One

OR Used This

```
newValues.put("admin_name", userName);
newValues.put("admin_phone", password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that Column name on Overridden Method of SqliteOpenHelper class like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   String CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + CartItemTable.TABLE_NAME + " ( " + CartItemTable.PRODUCT_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY ," + CartItemTable.CART_ITEM + " TEXT NOT NULL " + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE);
}
```

Upvote if it save your Time :)